# Finding polynomials which fulfill a certain condition

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I'm really struggling with the following problem.

> Find all polynomials with real coefficients that have the following
> property: for any positive real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ representing the
> lengths of the sides of a triangle, and any real numbers $x$, $y$, $z$
> such that $x+y+z=0$, the inequality holds
> $$W(a)yz + W(b)zx + W(c)xy \le 0. \tag{1}$$

I would really appreciate any tips or hints.

Edit.
During my attempts I found out that constant polynomials, i.e. $W(x) = \eta, \eta \ge 0$ fulfill the requirements. We have

$$W(a)yz + W(b)zx + W(c)xy = \eta(yz + zx + xy) = -\eta(x^2 + xy + y^2).$$

It's easy to show that $(x^2 + xy + y^2) \ge 0$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Moreover polynomial $W(x) = x^3$ does not fulfill the requirements provided in the exercise, it's pretty straightforward to a counterexample.

I also found how should the general form of LHS (1), i.e. for an arbitrary polynomial $W(x) = \eta_nx^n + ... + n_1x + \eta_0$ will be as follows
$$\eta_n(a^nyz + b^nzx + c^nxy) + ... + \eta_0(yz + zx + xy).$$

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  You must have found some examples for $W$, or at least ruled some out.

Comment: @lulu, sorry for that. Edited!

Comment: So, maybe it's the case that only the non-negative constants work.  To test that, I suggest proving that linear polynomials don't.  Even if this guess is wrong, maybe it leads to a useful new example. Helps to remark that, if $xyz\neq 0$, then exactly two of the products are negative.